# Split method throwing an IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to do a telephone directory using arrays (I have to use arrays). I am trying to write the method for adding new entries. I decided to add a new entry with a line that will be split using the `split` method into three parts (surname, initials, number) with tabs. When I tried to do the testing for the method I got thrown an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This is the `addEntry` method

```
@Override
public void addEntry(String line) {

    String[] entryLine = line.split("\\t");
    String surname = entryLine[0];
    String initial = entryLine[1];
    String number = entryLine[2];

    Entry entry = new Entry(surname, initial, number);
    count++;

    if (surname == null || initial == null || number == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill all the required fields, [surname,initials,number]");
    }
    if (count == entries.length) {
        Entry[] tempEntries = new Entry[2 * count];
        System.arraycopy(entries, 0, tempEntries, 0, count);
        entries = tempEntries;
    } else {
        int size = entries.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < entries.length; j++) {
                String one = entry.getSurname();

                if (one.toLowerCase().compareTo(surname.toLowerCase()) > 0) {
                    Entry tempE = entries[i];
                    entries[i] = entries[j];
                    entries[j] = tempE;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the entry I tried to add:

```
arrayDirectory.addEntry("Smith  SK  005598");
```

Comment: any particular reason why not use whitespace instead of tabs?

Comment: yeah its stated that I have to use tabs

Comment: Could you tell us where the IndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown?

Comment: @BillNaylor yeah it was thrown here: String initial = entryLine[1];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `String` you're entering is really

```
Smith  SK  005598
```

Then your splitting regex

```
\\t
```

(tab) cannot work, as the pieces are not separated by tabs.
Instead, you need to use

```
line.split("\\s+");
```

As `\s+` will match any number of spaces.
The output will correctly result in

```
[Smith, SK, 005598]
```

---

To have each piece separated by a tab, you'd use

```
Smith\tSK\t005598
```

Only then your original regex will work.

Comment: or if you just want to split on tabs, go: line.split("\t")  doubling the '\\' will escape '\'

Comment: @BillNaylor Yes. Also the version he's using now, "\\t", works fine too, but only if pieces are separated using "\t", as I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the logic:

```
if (surname == null || initial == null || number == null) 
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill all the required fields, [surname,initials,number]");
}
```

You should check the split line has length 3:

```
String[] entryLine = line.split("\\s+");
if (entryLine.length() != 3) 
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
}
```

Because those variables wont be null, the array access will cause IOOB error.

Also you should be putting

```
 Entry entry = new Entry(surname, initial, number);
    count++;
```

after the size check (better to put all precondition checks at the start of the method).